# Video not playing on startup

Tags: qt, opencv, video

I am trying to play a video in Qt using OpenCV. I am using the following code.

```
CvCapture *capture;
IplImge *frame;
cv::Mat source_image;
cv::Mat dest_image;
QTimer *imageTimer;

void MainWindow::onButtonClick()
 {
   capture = cvCaptureFromFile("/mp.mp4");
   while(capture)
  {
    frame = cvQueryFrame((capture);
    source_image = frame;
    cv::resize(source_image,source_image,cv::Size(420,180),0,0);
    cv::cvtColor(source_image,source_image,CV_BGR2RGB);
    QImage qimg = QImage((const unsigned char*) source_image.data,source_image.cols,source_imge.rows,QImage::Format_RGB888);
    label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimg));
    label->resize(label->pixmap()->size());
    qapp->processEvents();
   }
 }
```

When I try to play it on button click it is working fine. However when I write the same code in MainWindow constructor it gets finished unexpectedly. I want that the video should be displayed on screen start up and not when I click a button. What should I do for the same?
Thank You :)

Comment: Avoid blocking the event loop and processEvents, it won't work on startup. Better move the image creation to another thread

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any signal that I can send like when the window is opening get a slot and in that slot write the image creation code?

Comment: You could use QTimer::singleShot for delayed execution after the startup